# SharePoint: add properties to a webpart from code behind

Tags: c#, sharepoint

In the codebehind of a page.

How do i get hold of a webpart that exist on the page,
then add properties to that webpart using c#.

The webpart exists withing a webpartzone.

Do i need to do anything with SPWebPartManager?

Comment: You need not dispose it using finally as ur already using "Using";

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [SPWeb.GetLimitedWebPartManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.getlimitedwebpartmanager.aspx). The following example demonstrates updating a property in a list view web part:

```
using (SPLimitedWebPartManager webPartManager =
    SPContext.Current.Web.GetLimitedWebPartManager("default.aspx",
        PersonalizationScope.Shared))
{
    try
    {
        foreach (WebPart webPart in webPartManager.WebParts)
        {
            if (webPart.Title == "Web Part To Update")
            {
                ListViewWebPart listViewWebPart = (ListViewWebPart)webPart;
                // TODO: Set property on web part
                webPartManager.SaveChanges(listViewWebPart);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        webPartManager.Web.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Instead of `default.aspx` you need to use the name of the current page relative to the SPWeb.

Comment: thanks for this, how do i do the setting a property bit? eg in an exported .webpart file i have this property...how can i set that?
 <property name="AnchorLocation" type="string">/en</property>

Comment: Yes as you would've seen it is just set like any other property on a class.